# efficiently find max value of a property among all the elements

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Almost all the elements of my neo4j database has a property but name of that property might be different among labels. I wrote a query like below

```
MATCH (n)
MATCH ()-[e]-()
unwind [n.start_t,e.start_t,n.end_t,e.end_t,n.begin,e.begin,n.end] as l
return MIN(l) as min, MAX(l) as max
```

This runs fine but although I have less than 1000 elements it takes time like 7 seconds. How could I make this query more efficient ?

With RDMS databases these type of queries are working a lot faster

Comment: For each node/relationship, will only one of those properties be present? Or could several be there on a single node/relationship?

Comment: one or two will be present for each

Answer (score 1):

Your query performs a Cartesian product between `(n)` and `()-[e]-()`, that's likely why it is slow.

Do following instead:

```
MATCH (n)-[e]->()
unwind [n.start_t,e.start_t,n.end_t,e.end_t,n.begin,e.begin,n.end] as l
return MIN(l) as min, MAX(l) as max
```

**Edit:**
If you have nodes without relationships use optional match:

```
MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[e]->()
unwind [n.start_t,e.start_t,n.end_t,e.end_t,n.begin,e.begin,n.end] as l
return MIN(l) as min, MAX(l) as max
```

Comment: What if there are some nodes without any relationships?

Comment: I didn't know about Cartesian product. Why it is doing it ?

Comment: You have 2 unconnected patterns, it is similar to SQL query with 2 tables in `FROM` clause without any other conditions

Answer (score 0):

As Frant pointed out the cross product here is killing your performance. Note that this isn't just a cross between all nodes and all relationships, it's actually against 2x all your relationships since without a direction in the pattern each relationship will be matched to twice, once in each direction.

I think you would be better served calculating the min and max for all nodes first, then the min and max for all relationships, then the final calculation among the final results (using APOC for getting max and min among a list):

```
MATCH (n)
UNWIND [n.start_t, n.end_t, n.begin, n.end] as l
WITH min(l) as min, max(l) as max
MATCH ()-[e]->()
UNWIND [e.start_t, e.end_t, e.begin, e.end] as l
WITH min, max, min(l) as minR, max(l) as maxR
RETURN apoc.coll.min([min, minR]) as min, apoc.coll.max([max, maxR]) as max
```

At the point where you have min and max from the nodes, you're back down to a single row and ready to tackle the rest without cardinality issues.

EDIT

The APOC functions here are the cleanest way to get min or max within a single row.

Otherwise we may have to do something like this:

```
MATCH (n)
UNWIND [n.start_t, n.end_t, n.begin, n.end] as l
WITH min(l) as min, max(l) as max
MATCH ()-[e]->()
UNWIND [e.start_t, e.end_t, e.begin, e.end] as l
WITH min, max, min(l) as minR, max(l) as maxR
RETURN CASE WHEN min < minR THEN min ELSE minR END as min, CASE WHEN max > maxR THEN max ELSE maxR END as max
```

Comment: why you are using apoc for such a simple thing. Can't we make it with cql ?

Comment: Cypher's min() and max() are aggregation functions, working across multiple rows, not within lists or within a single row (this feature is on the backlog for later consideration). You could use a more complicated Cypher reduce() function here, but this approach is more readable.

Comment: You could use a CASE here to pick the least of the two and max of the two, that would probably be the simplest non-APOC approach. Added that to my answer.